# How to find the analytical solution to the following expression

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, algebra-precalculus

How do we find the analytical solution (exact solutions) to the following expression,

$-\left( \frac{A-x}{B-x}\right)=\exp(x),$
where $A$ and $B$ are known real values so that $A\neq0$, $B\neq0$ and $A\neq B$. I found numerical solutions. But how do we find exact solutions.

Comment: @DavidM. no need the $=0$, if $A=B$ then we have $-1=\exp(x)$: no solution

Comment: $A\neq 0$ and $B\neq 0$

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to try
to get it in a form
that can be solved using
the Lambert W function
(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function)
which solves
$x = ze^z$
for $z$ in terms of $x$.

I'm pretty sure that this can be done,
but I may not be able to do it myself.

$e^x
=-\left( \frac{A-x}{B-x}\right)
=-\left( \frac{B-x+(A-B)}{B-x}\right)
=-1-\left( \frac{(A-B)}{B-x}\right)
$.

Let $y = B-x$
and $c = B-A$.
Then
$x = B-y$ so
$e^{B-y}
=-1+\left( \frac{c}{y}\right)
$.
Therefore
$y e^{B-y}
= -y+c
$.

I'm not sure where
to go from here
and it's getting late,
so I'll stop
and hope this
inspires someone else.

Comment: Have you ever seen any algorithm for the solution of the generalized Lambert function (even for the simplest one like this) ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite the equation as
$$e^{-x}=-\frac{x-B}{x-A}$$ and have a look to equation $(4)$ in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1408.3999.pdf) which deals with the generalization of [Lambert function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).

This is a quite difficult problem and I strongly suggest you stay using numerical methods.

In the real domain, since the rhs must be positive, the solution is such that $\min (A,B)< x < \max (A,B)$.